# Spark: Joining Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I need to join two DataFrames as follows:

1. If keys match, get values from Right side.
2. If key on the left side doesn't exist on Right. Take values from left.
3. If key on the right side doesn't exist on Left. Take values from right.

What's the best way to do this using DataFrames? Previously I used to do this using 'cogroup' method of RDD, which is not available on DataFrames.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply perform `FULL OUTER JOIN` and use `COALESCE`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce

val dfLeft = sc.parallelize(Seq((2, "2L"), (3, "3L"))).toDF("kl", "vl")
dfLeft.show

## +---+---+
## | kl| vl|
## +---+---+
## |  2| 2L|
## |  3| 3L|
## +---+---+

val dfRight = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "1R"), (3, "3R"))).toDF("kr", "vr")
dfRight.show

## +---+---+
## | kr| vr|
## +---+---+
## |  1| 1R|
## |  3| 3R|
## +---+---+

dfLeft
  .join(dfRight, $"kl" === $"kr", "fullouter")
  .select(coalesce($"kl", $"kr").alias("k"), coalesce($"vr", $"vl").alias("v"))
  .show

## +---+---+
## |  k|  v|
## +---+---+
## |  1| 1R|
## |  2| 2L|
## |  3| 3R|
## +---+---+
```

Comment: This works in Spark 1.4.0 shell. But when I try using it in my Scala program, the 'toDF' method is not available for RDD class. I am using spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all you need `spark-sql` as well. Beyond that you have to import ` sqlContext.implicits` where `sqlContext` is `SQLContext` of your choice.

Comment: I've spark-sql_2.10 (version 1.4.0) as well, but SQLContext.implicits is not available. Anyway, I was able to create a DataFrame in a different way so I will accept this answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is available since 1.3:  `val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);   import sqlContext.implicits._`. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$